# problemas con url con parametro php

Tags: php

lo que sucede es que estoy teniendo problemas con una url que envio a un correo para posteriormente abrirlo y me lleve a una pagina, el correo tiene el siguiente link

https://www.mipagina.com/WEB/val.php/?cod=87ea5dfc8b8e

el link tiene un parámetro que es un código, cuando carga esta pagina me sale un formulario el cual tiene solo un botón que hace lo siguiente.

```
<form action="val2.php">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-rest" >ingresar</button>
</form>
```

pero el problema esta cuando le doy click y carga la pagina me la monta sobre el link anterior de esta forma
https://www.mipagina.com/WEB/val.php/val2.php lo cual debería ser https://www.mipagina.com/WEB/val2.php intente con ajax y tampoco se pudo y descubrí que al quitar el parámetro esto no pasa entonces no que que hacer porque requiero pasar ese parámetro del correo.

espero me puedan ayudar gracias...

Comment: No entiendo... Aquí ya pasas el dato: `https://www.mipagina.com/WEB/val.php/?cod=87ea5dfc8b8e` ¿para qué tienes un formulario si ya estás pasando el dato en la URL? ¿Por qué desististe de usar Ajax, cuando era la mejor opción para esto? Revisa si no tienes redirecciones en tu `.htaccess` que estén montando un php sobre otro.

Comment: volvi a ajax y en la dirección del ajax me dio por poner dos punto antes  var url = "../val2.php"; y parece que funciona vamos a ver como sale todo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambia la ruta del action

```
<form action="/val2.php">
```

La falta de la diagonal inicial se interpreta que irá a la ruta actual

Al agregarla se dirige hacia la raiz del sitio

Comment: +1 buena respuesta